# GORM relationship mapping

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes.A `request` that should be mapped to a `color`. `color` domain has 3 different options yellow, red, green (there could be more options (entries) at later point). So, when a user saves a new `request` I want it to be associated with one of the `colors`. In the `request` `_form` I'm going to have yellow, red, green in a `select` option from `Colors.list()`. Note: this is an overly simplified example of what my real model looks like.

**Question:**

- Which mapping association should I use? (I want each `request` to be associated with one `color`)
- How will I store `color` in my `request` when I get input from the form?

Answer (score 0):

For persisting the color, you've got a couple choices:

1. Save it as a string if the `color` is user-provided, or not from a predefined set.
2. Use or create an enum for each Color value that you anticipate having.  If the only three colors you have are yellow, red, and green, then this is definitely the better option for you.

Then, on the domain you simply need to define a field (of either your enum type, or String) with the name `color`, and it will be persisted as a varchar in the database.

In your controller, when the request comes through from the form, it will be stored in the `params` object, under the name that you gave your field, ie `params.yourColor`.

Comment: I was planning to have `color` as a separate domain class because at some point an admin could add/remove more items from it.

Answer (score 0):

So your select box options should have the id of the color as the value. The request domain class will simply have a `Color color`, if the color domain class is called color. If you are using data binding it should hook up just fine as long as the name of your select box is `color`. If you are not using data binding:

`new Request(...color: Color.get(params.nameOfSelectBox))`